# NEXT JS req.body undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

not sure what I'm doing wrong?

I'm getting undefined when trying to upload my form data to my supabase the data is coming to the API undefined but when I pass it to the function it prints what I want to send to the API in my submit handler.

```
export const Quote = () => {
  const [formIsValid, setFormIsValid] = useState(false);
  //----------------------------_FORM VALIDATION------------------------------------
  const {
    value: firstName,
    inputBlurChangeHandler: firstNameBlur,
    isValid: firstNameValid,
    hasError: firstNameInputHasError,
    valueChangeHandler: firstNameChangeHandler,
    reset: resetFirstName,
  } = useInput((value) => value.trim() !== "");



**hooks & useEffect removed to shorten question they are same as above but different names**

  console.log(formIsValid, "FORM IS VALID");


  const formSubmitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    //UNDEFINEDS
    await fetch("api/dbhandler", {
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        firstname: firstName,
        secondname: secondName,
        street: streetAddress,
        phone: phoneNumber,
        email: emailAddress,
        postal: postalCode,
        about: quoteDescription,
      },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": `text/plain`,
      },
    });
  };
```

API is coming as undefined in req. body but if I console log in the submit handler values are being passed to the function not sure what I am doing wrong

```
import { supabase } from "../../utils/supabaseClient";

const supabaseApiHandler = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.firstname);
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const firstname = req.body.firstname;
    const secondname = req.body.secondname;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const street = req.body.street;
    const postal = req.body.postal;
    const phone = req.body.phone;
    const about = req.body.about;

    const { data, error } = await supabase.from("quotes").insert([
      {
        firstname,
        secondname,
        email,
        street,
        postal,
        phone,
        about,
      },
    ]);
  }

  res.status(200).json({ name: "test" });
};

export default supabaseApiHandler;
```

Comment: Try using ````body: JSON.stringify(bodyData)````.

Comment: no luck with that  :(

Comment: Might be because you're also telling the server that your content isn't JSON, you're telling it that it's text.  Change it to ````"Content-Type": "application/json"````.

Comment: fixed it I made a`const reqBody = {
      firstname: firstName,
      secondname: secondName,
     ect....
    };`

Comment: `await fetch(`api/dbhandler`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(reqBody),`

Answer (score 16):

If you have the body parser disabled in the API route, req.body will be empty.

I accidentally left this code in without using another body parser.

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: Damn, I wasted an hour fiddling with postman and validator 